# CheckBoxList loop not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to select values in a `CheckBoxList` control based on a data source. I have five items in the `CheckBoxList` and three items in the data source, but in the loop I only get one item selected.

```
if (ddlUserId.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
   RoleDetails rd;
   rd = CatalogAccess.GetSingleUserRole(ddlUserId.SelectedValue.ToString());

   for (int i = 0; i < cblRoles.Items.Count; i++)
   {
      cblRoles.Items.FindByValue(rd.RoleID.ToString()).Selected = true;
   }
}
```

I tried this, but it still selects only one item:

```
RoleDetails rd;

for (int i = 0; i < cblRoles.Items.Count; i++)
{            
   rd = CatalogAccess.GetSingleUserRole(ddlUserId.SelectedValue.ToString());

   if (cblRoles.Items[i].Value == rd.RoleID.ToString())
      cblRoles.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```

CheckboxList bind code

```
  cblRoles.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetRoles();
  cblRoles.DataTextField = "RoleDetails";
  cblRoles.DataValueField = "RoleId";
  cblRoles.DataBind();
```

Comment: please share checkboxlist bind code

Comment: I have posted the bind code.

Comment: Does your CheckBoxList have multiple Checkboxes with the same value? You only ever get one RoleDetails object, therefore only one RoleID. So unless the answer to my question is yes, then you will only ever get one selected CheckBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use for loop you need to use index value (Here it is "i"), like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cblRoles.Items.Count; i++)
 {
   if(cblRoles.Items[i].Value == rd.RoleID.ToString())
           cblRoles.Items[i].Selected = true;
 }
```

Or you can use foreach as below:

Here i have created looping through items of checkbox list using foreach & item will be made selected id its value will match RoleId .

```
 foreach (ListItem li in cblRoles.Items)
    {
        if (rd.RoleID.ToString() ==  li.Value)
        {
            li.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            li.Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little explanation for what you are suggesting in the answer and why the code in OP is not getting the desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Still getting only one item selected. I have posted the code.

Comment: @ayha for selected user are there more than one role?

Comment: There are three roles for the selected user but it select the first role (roleId 1 in the table). I deleted the first item in the table and tried then it doesn't select anything else.

Comment: RoleDetails rd;
   rd = CatalogAccess.GetSingleUserRole(ddlUserId.SelectedValue.ToString());
 I think in this way you are fetching one role only. Please make sure you are fetching all assigned roles.